# Android dynamic navigation drawer menu items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, navigationview

I want to populate menu of Android navigation drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_bbnavigation_drawer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_bbnavigation_drawer"
        **app:menu="@menu/activity_bbnavigation_drawer_drawer"** />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How should I do that?

Comment: You want to populate the menu using xml menu layout or java code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the menu using [getMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getMenu()) method of `NavigationView` and then using the menu instance, you can perform operations like:

- Finding particular item by using [findItem(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int))
- Getting particular item from the particular index by using [getItem(int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#getItem(int))